# jquery autocomplete new field update

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I'm trying to add a field into array and fetch it with autocomplete through ajax requests. But each time the value doesn't get updated in autocomplete until page refresh is done.

```
$("#booker_name").autocomplete({
 source:bookername,
 select: function( event, ui ) {
    $(this).val(ui.item.label);
    $( "#booker_phone" ).val( ui.item.booking_phoneno);
    $( "#booker_email" ).val( ui.item.booking_email); //ui.item is your object from the array
    return false;
  }}).focus(function(){
      console.log(bookername);
      $.getJSON(url+companyId+'/', function(data) {
        $.each(data,function(key,value){
          bookername.push(value);
      });
      console.log(bookername);
   });

   }).focusout(function(){
     bookername = [];
 });
```

**ajax request code below:**

```
   $.ajax({            //send json-object to api and read response
       url: '/rapido/api/get_booker_list/',
       method: "POST",
       headers: {
       'X-CSRFToken': '{{ csrf_token }}'
        },
       contentType: 'application/json',
       data:JSON.stringify(booker),
       success: function(res) {
           swal({
              title:"Booker details added successfully",
              icon:"success"
            });
         }
      });
   });
```

Comment: Can you please explain in details. As I seen your Ajax call you are showing message like adding something

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer using jquery autocomplete options.

```
//something like this

$("#booker_name").autocomplete("option",{
  source:bookername
});
```